# Bash to create a JSON File Manifest

Tags: json, bash, md5, manifest

I have a bash script to output a file manifest with MD5 hashes as a JSON like so:

```json
{
 "files": [
    {
      "md5": "f30ae4b2e0d2551b5962995426be0c3a",
      "path": "assets/asset_1.png"
    },
    {
      "md5": "ca8492fdc3547af31afeeb8656619ef0",
      "path": "assets/asset_2.png"
    },
  ]
}
```

It will return a list of all files except .gdz.

The command I am using is:

```sh
echo "{\"files\": [$(find . -type f -print | grep -v \.gdz$ | xargs md5sum | sed 's/\.\///' | xargs printf "{\"md5\": \"%s\", \"name\": \"%s\"}," | sed 's/,$//')]}" > files.json
```

However, when I run this in production, it sometimes switches the MD5 hash and the file path around. I cannot work out why this is, does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run `md5sum` on all matching files, then do the rest with jq:

```sh
find . -type f -not -name '*.gdz' -exec md5sum -z {} + \
    | jq --slurp --raw-input '
        {
            files: split("\u0000")
                | map(split(" "))
                | map([
                    .[0],
                    (.[2:] | join(" "))
                ])
                | map({md5: .[0], path: .[1]})
        }'
```

The output of the `find` command is the output of running `md5sum` once on all matching files, with output records separated by null bytes.

The jq then does the following (and can almost certainly be optimized):

- `--slurp` and `--raw-input` read the whole input before any processing
- At the outermost level, we build an object with `files` as the key
- `split("\u0000")` creates an array from the null byte separated input records
- `map(split(" "))` converts each array element to an array split on blanks
- `map([ .[0], (.[2:] | join(" ")) ])` – to allow blanks in filenames, we create an array for each record where the first element is the md5 hash, and the second element is the concatenation of the rest, i.e., the filename; `[2:]` because we want to skip two blanks
- `map({md5: .[0], path: .[1]})` converts each two-element array into an object with the desired keys

Answer (score 2):

Doing this robustly in shell is a bit of pain; you have to worry about things like spaces in filenames (Which will break your current code), properly encoding and escaping your JSON strings (What if you have a file with quotes as part of the name?), etc.

A quick `perl` script that does the same, with the directory to scan passed as a command-line argument:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;
use Digest::MD5;
use JSON::PP; # Or JSON::XS if installed

my @hashes;

find(\&wanted, @ARGV);
print JSON::PP->new->ascii->encode({files => \@hashes});

sub wanted {
    if (-f $_ && $_ !~ /\.gdz$/) {
        my $name = $File::Find::name;
        $name =~ s!^\./!!;
        open my $f, "<:raw", $_ or
            die "Couldn't open $name: $!\n";
        push @hashes, { path => $name,
                        md5 => Digest::MD5->new()->addfile($f)->hexdigest
        };
        close $f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to create a JSON with tools that aren't designed for it is a task that's way too error prone. Please use a dedicated tool to properly create the JSON you want. I'd highly recommend [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -se '
  {
    "files":array{
      for $x in file:list(.,true())[not(ends-with(.,"/")) and not(ends-with(.,"gdz"))]
      return {
        "md5":substring(system(x"md5sum {$x}"),1,32),
        "path":$x
      }
    }
  }
'
```

- [`file:list(.,true())`](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#file-list) returns all files and directories in the current directory (and with the optional parameter `$recursive` set to `true()` all descendent directories are included as well).
- `[not(ends-with(.,"/")) and not(ends-with(.,"gdz"))]` filters the output of `file:list()` by removing the directories and "gdz"-files.
- [`system(x"md5sum {$x}")`](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-system) returns `md5sum` its stdout result as a string (and `substring(..,1,32)` obviously returns the first 32 characters).
  `x"..{..}.."` is an extended string, where `x"There are {1+2+3} elements"` for instance evaluates to "There are 6 elements".

Answer (score 1):

You may consider trying this one using `bash` and GNU tools `find` and `md5sum`. The script uses NUL terminated pathnames and escapes the relevant characters. It should work even if filenames contain newline characters.

```
#!/bin/bash

comma=
printf '{\n  "files": [\n'
while IFS= read -d '' -r line; do
    md5=${line:0:32}
    path=${line:34}
    path=${path//'\'/'\\'}
    path=${path//'"'/'\"'}
    path=${path//$'\b'/'\b'}
    path=${path//$'\f'/'\f'}
    path=${path//$'\n'/'\n'}
    path=${path//$'\r'/'\r'}
    path=${path//$'\t'/'\t'}
    printf '%s%4s{\n%6s"md5": "%s",\n%6s"path": "%s"\n%4s}' \
        "$comma" '' '' "${md5}" '' "${path}" ''
    comma=$',\n'
done < <(find . -type f ! -name '*.gdz' -exec md5sum -z {} +)
printf '\n  ]\n}\n'
```

or, also using the GNU `sed` (this version might be faster):

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '{\n  "files": ['
find . -type f ! -name '*.gdz' -exec md5sum -z {} + |
sed -Ez '
s/\\/\\\\/g
s/"/\\"/g
s/\x08/\\b/g
s/\f/\\f/g
s/\n/\\n/g
s/\r/\\r/g
s/\t/\\t/g
s/(.{32})..(.*)/\
    {\
      "md5": "\1",\
      "path": "\2"\
    }/
$!s/$/,/' | tr -d '\0'

printf '\n  ]\n}\n'
```

I believe both scripts are robust, assuming recent GNU tools.